# Get the specific count of each column using GROUP BY LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get the count of each items in columns using LINQ GroupBy, however I don't get the expected output.
Example :

```
 NAME      | Items | Items2
  1.ken    | asd   | zxc
  2.kent   | null  | zwe
  3.ken    | qwe   | null
```

Expected output:

```
NAME | Items | Items2
ken  |  2    |   1
kent |  0    |   1
```

Code:

```
var Data = Items.GroupBy(z => z.Name)
                .Select(s =>
                    new {
                        Name = s.Key,
                        Items = s.Count(q => q.Items),
                        Items2 = s.Count(x => x.Items2)
                    })
                .ToList();
```

The above code does not work.

Comment: What output you are getting? or any error

Comment: Are you always going to have two columns items and items2 or are you going to have more?

Comment: i have an error with s.Count(q=>q.Items) and s.Count(x=>x.Items2)

Comment: Can you post the definition of the class?

Comment: @KennethMontealto: `q.Items` is a string and `Count()` expect a boolean value, so `s.Count(q=>q.Items)` should be rewrite as `s.Count(q=>q.Items!=null)`, take a look into my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `null` values create issues in `Count()` in the expected output. So I suggest you to add a condition in `Count()` to exclude `null` values. So your query will look like:

```
var Data = Items.GroupBy(z => z.Name)
                .Select(s => 
                    new
                    { 
                        Name = s.Key, 
                        Items = s.Count(q => q.Items != null),
                        Items2 = s.Count(x => x.Items2 != null)
                    })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Redline in q.Items and x.Items2 , Same error with the posted codes. @un-lucky

Comment: @KennethMontealto: whats the error says? what is the type of `Items`? does it have properties like `Items` and `Items2`?

Comment: Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: all types are String
public string Name {get;set;} so on

Comment: @KennethMontealto: buddy you are using `s.Count(q=>q.Items)` and my suggestion was `s.Count(q=>q.Items!=null)` then how it works if you avoid  parts of code?

Comment: Sorry buddy i will post my whole Class to make it clear. Hang a little