# Why am I unable to do a count after a GroupBy with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public class LogViews
{
    public string DateYYMMDD { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public int LearnViews { get; set; }
    public int PracticeViews { get; set; }
    public int QuizViews { get; set; }
}

public class Views2Model
{
    public string DateYYMMDD { get; set; }
    public int Devices { get; set; }
    public int? LearnViews { get; set; }
    public int? PracticeViews { get; set; }
    public int? QuizViews { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is to get a count when grouped by the date:

```
var ViewCount = CreateExcelFile.ListToDataTable(Views
            .GroupBy(x => x.DateYYMMDD)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .Select(g => new Views2Model
            {
                DateYYMMDD = $"20{g.Key.Substring(0, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(2, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(4, 2)}",
                Devices = g.Count(),
                LearnViews = g.LearnViews.Count(),
                PracticeViews = g.PracticeViews.Count(),
                QuizViews = g.QuizViews.Count(),
            })
            .ToList());
```

But I am getting errors for g.LearnViews, g.PracticeViews and g.QuizViews

```
GetViews.cs(36,36): Error CS1061: 'IGrouping<string, LogViews>' does not contain a definition for 'LearnViews' and no accessible extension method 'LearnViews' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<string, LogViews>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Cosmos)
```

Can anyone give advice on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If `LearnViews` is type of int so you can't use Count since it's not IEnumerable . What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: @Selim `LearnViews` isn't type of `int`. `g.LearnViews` simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the specific count of each column using GROUP BY LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253900/get-the-specific-count-of-each-column-using-group-by-linq)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're treating a group as if it's a single record. In your select `g` represents a group. A single group object has a common `Key`, but it contains many "View" items. Therefore you need to `Sum` the individual record values for `LearnViews`, etc.

```
var ViewCount = CreateExcelFile.ListToDataTable(Views
            .GroupBy(x => x.DateYYMMDD)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .Select(g => new Views2Model
            {
                DateYYMMDD = $"20{g.Key.Substring(0, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(2, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(4, 2)}",
                Devices = g.Count(),
                LearnViews = g.Sum(gi => gi.LearnViews),
                PracticeViews = g.Sum(gi => gi.PracticeViews),
                QuizViews = g.Sum(gi => gi.QuizViews),
            })
            .ToList());
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you've messed up using succesive LINQ function. `g` is not `LogViews`, but it's `IEnumerable<LogViews>`. As I see in your code, You used `g.Count()`, but there is no `Count` function defined in `LogViews`, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can only do a `Count()` on an `IEnumerable` object.

`LearnViews` is an `int`.

What you want to do is : `LearnViews = g.Sum(v => v.LearnViews)`